# XMLReader from a string content

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm trying to generate XML from another XML using a XslTransform. I get both files (source XML and XSL transformation file) as string content, so I'm trying to pass the XSL file to XslTransform.Load() method as XmlReader. Now the XmlReader has to be created form a source string containing XSL file, so i try doing it like this:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(transformation.XsltContent);
memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
memStream.Position = 0;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(memStream);
```

and also tried using a StringReader:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(transformation.XsltContent));
```

Unfortunately, bot methods don't seems to work, the input seems to be ok, I even tried creating some basic one-element XML to pass, won't work either - reader contains {None}.

Could someone point out what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: "don't seems to work" is rather broad. Can you explain _what_ doesn't work. Include any error and exception information.

Comment: Did you close the xmlreader with XmlReader.close(), or alternatively enclose it in a using statement?

Comment: reader = {None} - that's what I see in debuger after I call XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(memStream), so i dont have a proper value to pass to XsltTransform.Load(reader)

Comment: same problem here, I get an exception, but no details

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The StringReader -> XmlReader approach is fine, you should stick to it. The reader reports none because it hasn't been read yet. Try calling Read() on it to see what happens then. The transformation will also call read on it.

Comment: I agree with fejesjoco, creating an XmlReader over a StringReader is fine, just pass it on to the Load method of XslCompiledTransform (or XslTransform if you still use .NET 1.x). Don't be worried about the debugger showing `{None}` for the XmlReader after its creation, that does not matter, the Load will consume that XmlReader just fine.

Comment: Remember: XmlReader and StringReader implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 172):

`XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(YourStringValue));`

Comment: You should dispose of that StringReader, perhaps by using `using`.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević it won't be disposed when `XmlReader` is disposed?

Comment: Remember: XmlReader and StringReader implement IDisposable.

Comment: From [the docs for StringReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=netcore-2.2): "This type implements the IDisposable interface, but does not actually have any resources to dispose. This means that disposing it by directly calling Dispose() or by using a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic) is not necessary."