# Fast replacement node names in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, fetchxml

I use a legacy service that manage Fetch CRM: `crmService.Fetch(fetchXml)`.

I get **XML string** result like this:

```
<resultset>
<result>
<new_categoria name="Cliente" formattedvalue="1">1</new_categoria>
<new_name>Admin</new_name>
<new_tipodecampanaid>{F8F29978-4E0F-AE92-FB43-48B4DC406B1F}</new_tipodecampanaid>
<statuscode name="Activo">0</statuscode>
</result>

<result>
<new_categoria name="Client" formattedvalue="1">1</new_categoria>
<new_name>Client</new_name>
<new_tipodecampanaid>{758341BA-4661-D694-6743-8D2DC875793E}</new_tipodecampanaid>
<statuscode name="Activo">0</statuscode>
</result>

<result>

</resultset>
```

We need (because **alias** not support for  **Fetch** method) replace several ***node names***:

1 - Replace **new_categoria** node name  by **org_category**

2 - Replace **new_name** node name  by **org_name**

3 - Replace **new_tipodecampanaid** node name  by **org_campaignid**

We need high peformance, maybe results can be huge.

Using `XmlDocument`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(fetchXMLResult);

XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("resultset");
foreach (XmlNode childNode in root.ChildNodes)
{

}
```

Using `XDocument`:

```
XDocument resultset = XDocument.Parse(fetchXMLResult);
if (resultset.Root == null || !resultset.Root.Elements("result").Any())
{
    return;
}
resultset.Root.Elements("result")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For speed you could run through the file using an `XmlReader` and write each node you read to a new file using an `XmlWriter`.

See [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mfussell/2005/02/12/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you have large xml file always use XmlReader.  Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME);

            writer.WriteStartElement("resultset");
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "result")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("result");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement result = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    result.Element("new_categoria").Name = "org_category";
                    result.Element("new_name").Name = "org_name";
                    result.Element("new_tipodecampanaid").Name = "org_campaignid";

                    writer.WriteRaw(result.ToString());
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use following : string xml = "";
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

Comment: Maybe include comment code in answer. View
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518544/xmlreader-from-a-string-content
*Remember: XmlReader and StringReader implement IDisposable.*